# Net-SNMP share variables between MIB modules

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have written multiple Net-SNMP MIB modules that need that share a global structure between them.

The options I have thought of:

1. Find a way to have 2 or more MIB modules use common code. (not sure if this is possible)
2. Combine the MIB modules into one MIB module set up structure during init__MODULE function. (Is this bad practice it would be about 10 handlers in the module)
3. Linux shared memory (not really looking to do this)

Other info:
The MIB modules are being compiled into the master agent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what those "different MIB modules" actually are:

- objects from **different MIB files** - **do not do this**, as the common code will disobey some standards (one MIB file represents one particular agents ; agent do not suppose to know about other agents)
- ***different* objects** from the same MIB (in this scalars and tables ) - yes, you can, but I would **not recommend** doing this. It is better to you use some specific API's functions for tables separately as they could be really helpful.
- **scalars from the same branch** ( as in 1.3.6.1.2.1.5 *icmp* branch of *MIB-2* MIB) - **YES**, that will good choice to generalize your code. Here You can use *scalar_group* handler.